# How to pattern match large Scala case classes?

Tags: scala, pattern-matching

Consider the following Scala case class:

```
case class WideLoad(a: String, b: Int, c: Float, d: ActorRef, e: Date)
```

Pattern matching allows me to extract one field and discard others, like so:

```
someVal match {
    case WideLoad(_, _, _, d, _) => d ! SomeMessage(...)
}
```

What I would like to do, and what's more relevant when a case class has ~20 odd fields, is to extract only a few values in a way that does not involve typing out `WideLoad(_, _, _, _, _, some, _, _, _, thing, _, _, interesting)`.

I was hoping that named args could help here, although the following syntax doesn't work:

```
someVal match {
    case WideLoad(d = dActor) => dActor ! SomeMessage(...)
    //              ^---------- does not compile
}
```

Is there any hope here, or am I stuck typing out many, many `_, _, _, _`?

**EDIT**: I understand that I can do `case wl @ WideLoad(...whatever...) => wl.d`, yet I'm still wondering whether there's even terser syntax that does what I need without having to introduce an extra `val`.

Comment: Even with 4 or 5 fields, all the underscores make it pretty hard to read.  A named parameter syntax would improve readability a lot, but as far as I know nothing like this exists yet.

Comment: I was under the impression that long parameter lists are something to avoid in general.

Comment: you meant case WideLoad (d == dActor)

Comment: There's a SIP about this very issue: https://issues.scala-lang.org/browse/SI-6524

Comment: @JamesMoore Regarding the issue, I wonder whether inspiration can be taken from import statement syntax.  We have that `import org.apache.{foo,bar=>bat}` imports foo and bar, renaming the latter to bat.  In the same way we could do `case WideLoad{d=>actorRef} if actorRef == 42 => SomeMessage(...)`

Answer (score 39, accepted):

I don't know if this is appropriate, but you can also build an object just to match that field, or that set of fields (untested code):

```
object WideLoadActorRef {
  def unapply(wl: WideLoad): Option[ActorRef] = { Some(wl.d) }
}

someVal match {
  case WideLoadActorRef(d) => d ! someMessage
}
```

or even

```
object WideLoadBnD {
  def unapplySeq(wl: WideLoad): Option[(Int,ActorRef)] = { Some((wl.b,wl.d)) }
}

someVal match {
  case WideLoadBnD(b, d) => d ! SomeMessage(b)
}
```

Comment: I like your idea a lot. It does exactly what I need, with little extra syntax, and explicitly defined intent, type safety, etc. It's a great stop gap solution until such time when I've refactored this code to have smaller case classes.

Answer (score 17):

You can always fall back to guards. It's not really nice, but better than normal pattern matching for you monster case classes :-P

```
case class Foo(a:Int, b:Int, c:String, d:java.util.Date)

def f(foo:Foo) = foo match {
  case fo:Foo if fo.c == "X" => println("found")
  case _ => println("arrgh!")
}

f(Foo(1,2,"C",new java.util.Date())) //--> arrgh!
f(Foo(1,2,"X",new java.util.Date())) //--> found
```

That said I think you should rethink your design. Probably you can logically group some parameters together using case classes, tuples, lists, sets or maps. Scala *does* support nested pattern matching:

```
case class Bar(a: Int, b:String)
case class Baz(c:java.util.Date, d:String)
case class Foo(bar:Bar, baz:Baz)

def f(foo:Foo) = foo match {
   case Foo(Bar(1,_),Baz(_,"X")) => println("found")
   case _ => println("arrgh!")
}

f(Foo(Bar(1,"c"),Baz(new java.util.Date, "X"))) //--> found
f(Foo(Bar(1,"c"),Baz(new java.util.Date, "Y"))) //--> arrgh!
```

Comment: Yes, I am refactoring towards that goal. It may be easier to do this than build sand castles akin to what I proposed in my question.

Answer (score 1):

You can just specify the type in the matched pattern:

```
case class WideLoad(a: String, b: Int, c: Float, d: ActorRef, e: Date)

val someVal = WideLoad(...)

someVal match {
    case w: WideLoad => w.d ! SomeMessage(...)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can create a new case class which is a summary of your larger case class

```
case class WideLoad(a: String, b: Int, c: Float, d: ActorRef, e: Date)
case class WideLoadSummary(d: ActorRef, e: Date)
```

And then pattern match as normal.

```
val someVal = WideLoadSummary(wideload.d, wideload.e)

someVal match {
    case WideLoadSummary(d, _) => d ! SomeMessage(...)
}
```