# Scala : Pattern matching with Option[Foo] and parameter of Foo

Tags: scala, pattern-matching, scala-option

How can rewrite the following to make it more 'Scala way' or use just one match?

```
case class Foo(bar: Any)
val fooOpt = Some(Foo("bar as String"))

def isValid(p: Any) = p match {
   case _ @ (_: String | _: Int) => true
   case _ => false
}

//Is it possible to check for the type of bar directly in this if statement?
fooOpt match {
    case Some(f) if isValid(f.bar) => doSomething
    case _ => doSomethingElse
}
```

One alternative would be using the isInstanceOf.

```
fooOpt match {
     case Some(f) if f.bar.isInstanceOf[String] => doSomething
     case Some(f) if f.bar.isInstanceOf[Int] => doSomething //could also rewrite to use just one case
     case _ => doSomethingElse
}
```

Is there other way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can all be done in one big pattern match:

```
fooOpt match {
   case Some(Foo(_: Int | _: String)) => doSomething
   case _ => doSomethingElse
}
```

If you want to get the `Int` or `String` out, just split that `case`:

```
fooOpt match {
   case Some(Foo(i: Int)) => doSomething
   case Some(Foo(s: String)) => doSomething
   case _ => doSomethingElse
}
```

Comment: Cheers! Makes perfect sense. Had a feeling that there was some easy and simple solution out there! Thanks

Comment: btw, if Foo had multiple params, how would you select the 'bar' without describing them all?

Comment: @Bruno Just use underscore patterns for the other params. So something like `Some(Foo(i: Int, _, _))` you you add two more params to `Foo`.

Comment: that is what I mean with 'without describing them all'. The class that I am working with has a lot of params, and it will not look good if I do that for all of them (will be hard to read and error prone). Was thinking if there was a way to do it similar to: new Foo(bar = " some value"). Where we explicitly select the param

Comment: @Bruno Oh sorry I misunderstood. :). There is a way, but it isn't direct. You end up making your own extractor for just that field. Something like [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3475927/3072788).

Answer (score 1):

> Is there other way?

Although the solution with one big patten match works(and can be used if you really can't change `bar` to anything more specific than `Any`), it is not a proper 'Scala way' of dealing with this situations in general if you have control over `Foo`.

A better way would be to make Foo generic:

```
case class Foo[T](bar: T)
```

And have either a generic `doSomething`, if it can work with any particular `T`:

```
def doSomething[T](foo: Foo[T]): SomeType = ???
```

or to have different versions of it for different possible `T`'s you have, if it should react on them differently:

```
def doSomethingWithString(foo: Foo[String]): SomeType = ???
def doSomethingWithInt(foo: Foo[Int]): SomeType = ???
```

Then you can use it just like this:

```
val fooOpt = Some(Foo("bar as String"))
fooOpt.map(doSomething).orElse(doSomethingElse)
```

or like this:

```
val fooOptString = Some(Foo("bar as String"))
fooOptString.map(doSomethingWithString).orElse(doSomethingElse)

val fooOptInt = Some(Foo(1))
fooOptInt.map(doSomethingWithInt).orElse(doSomethingElse)
```

So, in this case compiler checks types for you, answering to:

> Is it possible to check for the type of bar directly?

And in many situations you can avoid using pattern match at all, using methods like `map`, `orElse`, etc. with proper typing. This might be an answer for this:

> could also rewrite to use just one case